# Prime solutions to a congruence modulo a semi-prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

Let $p$ and $q$ be primes.

Besides $\{3,13\}$ and $\{13,61\}$, find other solutions $\{p,q\}$ to the congruence
$$ 1+ p+q+p^2+q^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {pq}$$
or show that there are none.

Comment: suggest you view several of the questions and answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vieta-jumping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that this can be finished. There is at least one more solution with ratio 5, namely
$$ p = 22419767768701 \; , \; \; \; q = 107419560853453 $$

Given any natural numbers $x < y,$ we get a new solution to 
$$ x^2 - 5xy + y^2 + x + y + 1 = 0  $$
with
$$ (x,y) \mapsto (y, 5y-x-1)  $$
This is called Vieta Jumping on this site and in contests. In the simple program below, if we get two primes in a row printed out, that pair satisfies your question.

```
int main()
{
  mpz_class bound = 1000000000;
  bound *= bound;
  mpz_class x = 1;
   mpz_class y = 3;

while (y < bound)
{
mpz_class z = 5 * y - x - 1; 
  x = y;
  y = z;
  cout << y << "   =  " << mp_Factored(y) << endl;
}

   cout << endl << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
13   =   13
61   =   61
291   =   3 97
1393   =   7 199
6673   =   6673
31971   =   3 10657
153181   =   7 79 277
733933   =   127 5779
3516483   =   3 73 16057
16848481   =   13 1296037
80725921   =   43 1877347
386781123   =   3 1531 84211
1853179693   =   1853179693
8879117341   =   26947 329503
42542407011   =   3 13^3 6454621
203832917713   =   65437 3114949
976622181553   =   976622181553
4679277990051   =   3 7 199 1119712369
22419767768701   =   22419767768701
107419560853453   =   107419560853453
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY 
WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? factor(22419767768701)
%1 = 
[22419767768701 1]

? factor(107419560853453 )
%2 = 
[107419560853453 1]

?
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Alright, I ran the sequence up pretty high, taking $x_0 = 1,$ then $x_1 = 3,$ then $x_2 = 13,$ $x_3 = 61,$ after which:

```
2 :  13   Prime  
3 :  61   Prime  
6 :  6673   Prime  
14 :  1853179693   Prime  
18 :  976622181553   Prime  
20 :  22419767768701   Prime  
21 :  107419560853453   Prime  
56 :  70293079987740435611353046917706109661   Prime  
300 :     Prime  
384 :     Prime  
447 :     Prime  
477 :     Prime  
878 :     Prime  
1000  milestone not really Prime 
2000  milestone not really Prime 
3000  milestone not really Prime 
4000  milestone not really Prime 
5000  milestone not really Prime 
5906 :     Prime  
6000  milestone not really Prime
```

There is another aspect: there are no **positive integer** solutions to $$  x^2 - kxy+y^2 + x + y + 1 = 0$$
for integer  $k \geq 3$ unless $k=5.$  Here is the diagram that shows the geometric part of the argument when $k=7.$

[image]

Here is the diagram for $k=5$ showing the "fundamental solution" between the diagonal lines at $(1,1)$
[image]

Comment: That's very cool.  When you say it can't be finished, do you mean there would be an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: @RenéGy there might be, but I don't know any way to decide finiteness or lack of it. If there is a theorem giving finiteness, most likely it gives no specific upper bounds on the primes or count of primes: such results are usually "ineffective" in that they say something happens for "sufficiently large" numbers but give no explicit size for sufficiency

Comment: the primes in this sequence seem to be more and more rare. So the probability to find 2 primes one just after the other would then be even smaller. In order to find new solution, shouldn't we try other ratio than 5 ?

Comment: the ratio $k$ such that $x^2-kxy+y^2+x+y+1=0$ can have integer solution must be such that all the prime factors $p$ of $k+2$ verify  $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, right ?  the next possible value for $k$ would then be $k=11$. Would you try your computation with $k=11$ ?

Comment: @RenéGy I have added a diagram. This shows he approach of Hurwitz (1907). For a specific $k,$ once we confirm that there are no integer points on the hyperbolic arc between the two lines drawn, it follows that no (positive) integer solutions are possible for that $k.$ I have answered many similar questions with proofs: click on the tag "vieta-jumping" for a list of those, about 45 questions I think. I added that as one of the tags just below your question.

Comment: ok thanks for the insight. I didn' know about "Vieta jumping".